# How to move Java Installation on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, rhel

I am trying to move the Java installation on an RHEL system. `which java` currently returns `/usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java`, and I want it to reference `/usr/bin/java`. There appears to be a symbolic link `java` at `/usr/bin/java`, but frankly I'm not really sure how those work. Can I move the `java` directory at `/usr/java` somewhere? I need it to reference the aforementioned directory for my orchestration tools to work correctly; the `JAVA_HOME` is actually what is throwing the error, but I figure that moving the java installation itself would be vital to that.

Comment: Your init scripts have added `/usr/java/latest/jre/bin` before `/usr/bin` to your PATH variable, so it discovers `/usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java` before `/usr/bin/java`. If you don't know how to modify your init files to avoid that, you can override it by adding `/usr/bin` to the front again with `export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by first changing my init scripts as that other guy suggested (in this case, I removed some outdated stuff from my `.bash_profile` and added `/usr/bin` to the beginning of my PATH) and then creating new symbolic links in the `/usr/bin` directory. This meant I needed to move the Java directory into the new `JAVA_HOME` location, delete the old symlinks to `java` and `javac` (well, I just renamed them to have `-old` prefixes just in case), and create new symlinks going to the new (desired) `JAVA_HOME` from `/usr/bin`, and I dynamically set the `JAVA_HOME` using `readlink`.

Comment: If it wasn't obvious, I had to read up on how symlinks work to solve this.